# Is there any difference between building / running an application targeting .Net 4 having installed .Net 4 or .Net 4.5?

Tags: c#, .net, frameworks

Is there any difference building / running an application targeting .Net 4 if you have installed only .Net 4 Framework or .Net 4.5 Framework?

A colleague of mine said that even if the application targets .Net 4 installing the 4.5 makes a difference and I'm unsure.

Comment: I think it was designed to be backwards compatible, but you can never be sure if your code is really obscure and uses features marked obsolete.

Comment: NET 4.5 is an "in-place upgrade" of .NET 4, so even if you target .Net 4 you will be using .NET 4.5, see http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NETVersioningAndMultiTargetingNET45IsAnInplaceUpgradeToNET40.aspx

Comment: @Pieter21: do you mean 4.5 with 4? Have in mind that the projects are targeting 4 Framework and they are not going to be changed.

Comment: *"Makes a difference"* In what? What does that mean? What are you "afraid" would happen?

Comment: @Jaco: excellent, thanks, that means "Yes". Can you put it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NET 4.5 is an "in-place upgrade" of .NET 4, so even if you target .Net 4 you will be using .NET 4.5,  see http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NETVersioningAndMultiTargetingNET45IsAnInplaceUpgradeToNET40.aspx.

Summarising this blog, there are three major version of .NET that can be installed side by side:

- .NET 1 (1.1)
- .NET 2 (2/3/3.5)
- .NET 4 (4/4.5)

The "minor" versions are in place upgrades

Answer (score 1):

I've had *massive* problems with HgLab (which is an on-premise ASP.NET application) targeting .NET 4.0 and being built on a server with .NET 4.5 installed.

I don't use anything fancy, only stable public APIs and *explicitly* target .NET 4.0. Yet it kept on crashing deep inside `kernelbase.dll` on 64-bit systems, producing indecipherable crashdumps and generally behaving very weirdly.

What I ended up doing was enabling 32-bit application support in 64-bit version of IIS - this seems to have solved the problem. But generally, if you want to really target .NET 4.0, do your builds on a build server with *only* .NET 4.0 installed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, here's an example:

The following console app should throw an `UnobservedTaskException` on a system without .Net 4.5 or later installed, but it will loop forever if .Net 4.5 or later has been installed:

```
private static void Main()
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { throw new InvalidOperationException("Erk"); });

    while (true)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    }
}
```

You're supposed to be able to [configure this behaviour in `App.Config`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj160346%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) according to Microsoft, but it doesn't work for me at all.

Comment: @IgnacioSolerGarcia If you target .Net 4.0 this happens.