# Is there any difference between targeting an application to Framework 4 or Framework 4.5 if you don't use any 4.5 APIs?

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, frameworks, .net-4.5

after looking at these posts:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NETVersioningAndMultiTargetingNET45IsAnInplaceUpgradeToNET40.aspx

http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Mar/13/NET-45-is-an-inplace-replacement-for-NET-40

and asked this question:

[Is there any difference between building / running an application targeting .Net 4 having installed .Net 4 or .Net 4.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32203875/is-there-any-difference-between-building-running-an-application-targeting-net)

Now I have a similar but different question. As the CLR is replaced by .Net 4.5 is there any difference if I change a working application from targeting .Net 4 to target .Net 4.5? Only this change.

Do I need to regression the application or can I be 100% that the application will work the same as the CLR is the same and I am not using any new feature of .Net 4.5?

Comment: You can't get a warranty here, no point in asking for one.  There is one wrinkle that is specific to 4.5.  When you target 4.0 then your user can run the app on XP and you didn't test that.  Probably works okay but there certainly is some comfort in knowing that you'll never get a support call like that.  Well, other than the "it doesn't work on XP" call.

Comment: @HansPassant: thanks. That was the kind of answer I was looking for. The app is huge and regressing it wouldn't be funny. Based on what you say I feel safe enough to not regression the whole app. If you put it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) in the comments,

- a .NET 4.0 application will run on Windows XP where a .NET 4.5 application doesn't

But there's a bit more than that technically

- .NET 4.5 applications will not run on .NET 4.0 framework, so you also loose [Windows Vista and Vista SP1 as well as Server 2003 and Server 2008](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z6watww%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
- .NET 4.5 is preinstalled on [Windows 8 ans Server 2012](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z6watww%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), so you might need to adapt your installer if it comes with .NET
- [Itanium IA64](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z6watww%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is supported in .NET 4.0 but not in .NET 4.5

and to do organizationally

- update manuals and the company website
- follow promised phase-out times, e.g. announce the discontinuation of OS some months in advance
- ...